# Inserting values in to netezza using a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, netezza

I'm working with netezza database and have a requirement to insert a Y flag for stores in California. I wrote the below procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_NEW_PROCEDURE() RETURNS BOOL
EXECUTE AS OWNER LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
FOR rec in SELECT * from test_table 
LOOP
if rec.state_code ='CA'
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO test_table (california_stores)' || 'values('y')';
END LOOP;
END;
END_PROC;
```

when I call the procedure using call MY_NEW_PROCEDURE() I get an error at line EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. I'm not sure what change I need to make here.

Comment: I only want to insert a flag based on store location. If stored procedure is not the way. I would welcome other ways of accomplishing this as well. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you need to escape your single quotes around the 'y'.  Probably should be values(''y'')';

Comment: @ShaunPeterson I escaped the Y and executed it. I am getting the below error

Comment: You didn't post the new error?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about netezza, but below is the procedure I used to test this (using SQL developer).

Works fine for me, although it would make more sense to update the row to set california_stores to 'Y'rather than insert a new row with california_stores = 'Y' for each calafornia store that you have.....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MY_NEW_PROCEDURE" as
    rec test_table2%rowtype;
BEGIN
   FOR rec in (SELECT * from test_table2) LOOP
      if rec.state_code = 'CA' then
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO test_table2 (california_stores)' || 'values(''y'')';
      end if;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the second error, but it looks to me like your insert statement isn't going to do what you want anyway. If the `rec` variable contains the attribute `state_code` and you're inserting a single value to `test_table` then the record will simply be empty except for a 'Y' in `california_stores`.

I'm going to guess that you're getting an error now either because of the spacing in the insert statement `insert into test_table (california_stores)values('y')` or because you didn't terminate the execute statement with a semicolon. The plsql for that line should be

`execute immediate 'insert into test_table (california_stores) values (''y'');';`